# Meteor development on slow connections

Tags: meteor

Meteor is practically unusable on slow connections in general and in China in particular. The great firewall is not kind to Meteor and its users and as most consumer-level VPNs only cover browser traffic I'm curious as for if there are any workarounds to the below:

What happens is that when you start the app:

```
$ meteor
```

You'll in many cases get either:

```
 Downloading meteor-tool@x.x.x...
```

or..

```
 Downloading packages
```

After which the console is stuck for 10+ min and then you get one of the the below:

```
Unable to update package catalog (are you offline?)

Could not springboard to release: METEOR@x.x
```

Has anyone found a workflow for Meteor development on slow connections that is not causing their blood pressure to peak on a daily basis?

Answer (score 2):

Here in mexico, i have the same issue i cannot even download meteor on my pc, and finally when i downloaded meteor, it was impossible to download android sdk or some mobile platform, so i found this solution (If your purpose is to get started on meteor).

[Nitrous.io](https://www.nitrous.io), here just create one account, and for free you will have 1 box to play around, just select the type of box as `meteor`, and its donde, meteor is already installed, take a look

Comment: if you need help with meteor and have the box online just add me and we can talk ethan.rosanoo@gmail GC

Comment: sup @oskare, you find a solution?